# hp sim Firmware And Software Revision (how does it get that data)

Tags: linux, hp, snmp, hp-proliant

I have installed all the insight agents, and I have sim showing the Firmware And Software Revision information on the System status screen.

Can anyone explain how sim is getting that information from the server?

I suspect that it is exposed through either a snmp MIB, or sim is logging into the system management homepage, and querying that information directly.

I would like to pull the firmware revisions and use them elsewhere.

(if the suggestion is to pull them out of the sim database, then I am using the linux 6.2 version so I would have to look into where that is storing the data, I would prefer to get the data straight from the client machine)

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the agents use SNMP.  If you stop SNMP (or SNMP is not functioning correctly), the System Home Page shows all the section, but no data, plus it takes an age to load.  On Windows, they can use SNMP or WMI - you can configure this in the agent.

If you do an SNMP walk on .1.3.6.1.4.1.232, you'll see the data that the agent accesses (assuming your PC is a permitted manager).